# Selenium WebDriver: findElement() in each WebElement from List<WebElement> always returns contents of first element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
Page page = new Page();
page.populateProductList( driver.findElement( By.xpath("//div[@id='my_25_products']") ) );

class Page
{
    public final static String ALL_PRODUCTS_PATTERN = "//div[@id='all_products']";

    private List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void populateProductList(final WebElement pProductSectionElement)
    {
        final List<WebElement> productElements = pProductSectionElement.findElements(By.xpath(ALL_PRODUCTS_PATTERN));

        for ( WebElement productElement : productElements ) {
            // test 1 - works 
            // System.out.println( "Product block: " + productElement.getText() );
            final Product product = new Product(productElement);
            // test 2 - wrong
            // System.out.println( "Title: " + product.getUrl() );
            // System.out.println( "Url: " + product.getTitle() );
            productList.add(product);
        }

        // test 3 - works
        //System.out.println(productElements.get(0).findElement(Product.URL_PATTERN).getAttribute("href"));
        //System.out.println(productElements.get(1).findElement(Product.URL_PATTERN).getAttribute("href"));
    }
}

class Product
{
    public final static String URL_PATTERN = "//div[@class='url']/a";
    public final static String TITLE_PATTERN = "//div[@class='title']";

    private String url;
    private String title;

    public Product(final WebElement productElement)
    {
        url = productElement.findElement(By.xpath(URL_PATTERN)).getAttribute("href");
        title = productElement.findElement(By.xpath(TITLE_PATTERN)).getText();
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

The webpage I am trying to 'parse' with Selenium has a lot of code. I need to deal with just a smaller portion of it that contains the products grid.
To the `populateProductList()` call I pass the resulting portion of the DOM that contains all the products.
(Running that XPath in Chrome returns the expected all_products node.)

In that method, I split the products into 25 individual WebElements, i.e., the product blocks.
(Here I also confirm that works in Chrome and returns the list of nodes, each containing the product data)

Next I want to iterate through the resulting list and pass each `WebElement` into the `Product()` constructor that initializes the `Product` for me.
Before I do that I run a small test and print out the product block (see test 1); individual blocks are printed out in each iteraion.

After performing the product assignments (again, xpath confirmed in Chrome) I run another test (**see test 2**).

**Problem: this time the test returns only the url/title pair from the FIRST product for EACH iteration.**

Among other things,  I tried moving the `Product`'s `findElement()` calls into the loop and still had the same problem. Next, I tried running a `findElement**s**()` and do a `get(i).getAttribute("href")` on the result; this time it correctly returned individual product URLs (see test 3).

Then when I do a `findElements(URL_PATTERN)` on a single `productElement` inside the loop, and it magically returns ALL product urls... This means that `findElement()` always returns the first product from the set of 25 products, whereas I would expect the `WebElement` to contain only one product.

I think this looks like a problem with references, but I have not been able to come up with anything or find a solution online.

Any help with this? Thanks!

java 1.7.0_15, Selenium 2.45.0 and FF 37

Comment: @alecxe this is a commitment that, once the product is assigned the result, it is not going to be modified and, if this is the question, removing that does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the XPATH of the Product locators.

Below xpath expression in selenium means you are looking for a matching element which **CAN BE ANYWHERE** in document. Not relative to the parent as you are thinking!!

```
//div[@class='url']/a
```

This is why it always returns the same first element.

So, in order to make it relative to the parent element it should be as given below. (just a . before //)

```
public final static String URL_PATTERN = ".//div[@class='url']/a";
public final static String TITLE_PATTERN = ".//div[@class='title']";
```

Now you make it search for matching child element relative to the parent.

XPATH in selenium works as given below.

```
/a/b/c   --> Absolute - from the root

//a/b    --> Matching element which can be anywhere in the document (even outside the parent).

.//a/b   --> Matching element inside the given parent
```

Comment: **Thank you, Vinoth!** I did not know `//` was going outside the parent. That `.` did the trick.